# MySQL Query and PHP Script Tuning: How can I find the problems?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, logging, profiling

I have inherited a site running several different software packages worked on by several different people over several years, with lots of modifications and addons throughout.

How can I systematically, pervasively, and I hope automatically log/monitor/find scripts that use slow queries, persistent connections, unindexed joins, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variety of tools to service these needs:

- [MySQL Enterprise Monitor Query Analyzer (Costs $$$)](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)

  - This will log, monitor, and find slow queries, un-indexed joins, and persistent connections, as well as giving advice on how to improve MySQL performance
- [mysqltuner (opensource perl script)](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl)

  - This will debug you MySQL configuration and give suggestions on how to adjust it to improve performance
- [mtop (like top, but for MySQL, free)](http://mtop.sourceforge.net/)

  - This will monitor slow queries
- [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [Web Grind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) (PHP performance, free)

  - This will log, monitor and find slow scripts
- [New Relic (good for finding slow requests, and the reason why they where slow, free or paid)](http://newrelic.com/)

  - This will log, monitor, and find slow scripts and queries
- [MySQL Monitor Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlmt/) (Java, free)

  - This will log, monitor, and find slow queries, and persistent connections

Also on a site note, another awesome tool is [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) (free) which provides full database management (including tables, views, triggers, functions, procedures, etc), diagramming, and schema/data comparison functions.

I personally recommend, in order:

- New Relic (free, or paid plan if its within budget)
- mysqltuner (only needs to be used once or twice)
- MySQL Enterprise Monitor (too expensive for most cases, but very good)

Answer (score -1):

You can enable [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html). `mysqltuner` is also good as a starting point to tune most important params.